# Cross platform and language plugin system

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, cross-platform, system

I'm looking for a good, cross platform and cross language plugin system in C++.

I'm currently using Qt as a framework.

I need the plugins to be cross platform, and to be able to be created in different scripting languages (python, ruby, etc.) and Java.

Anyone here knows a good system for that?

Thx,

bl00dshooter.

Comment: I think this will introduce an overwhelming amount of problems in later stages of software development / life-cycle. Have you considered narrowing down the scripting languages to a single one - most of them (like Python) are already cross platform?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to support several scripting languages instead of plugins.  The term "plugin" usually indicates a library that extends your application (dynamically) in some way.  These are usually compiled in the same language as the base application.  If you are looking at adding a scripting language to your application, Lua is a good starting point, but you will likely want to stick with 1 language as the complexity of supporting multiple scripting languages is not worth the minor benefit.

Comment: Typical multi-language plugin architectures make use of c-language binding (`extern "C"` in c++). Python, Lua, Fortran, and many, many other languages implement c-language bindings. Like @brokenisfixed said, if you are looking to support scripting in your application, it would be a good idea to pick one language (WoW picked lua) ans stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/204202899?cid=RSSfeed_DDJ_Cpp) a great article on how to write a portable plugin management system for C/C++. It demonstrates that such a system is hard to develop. It should have links in it ...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to keep an eye on the [pureImage](https://pureimage.flll.jku.at/) framework, although Python and Ruby bindings are not implemented yet. We use it for image processing, but the core should be general enough to work for other domains as well.

*(disclaimer: I am participating in pureImage development)*